# Relocating .NET global assembly cache?

Tags: .net-framework

Is it possible, and how, to relocate the [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) global assembly cache?

I'd like to do this to put this cache in a faster drive. Resource Monitor is showing me that these files are very often read, and I think this can speed up a bit my system.

I'm working with .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading under [Relocating the GAC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4352/Demystifying-the-NET-Global-Assembly-Cache).

The explanation sounds hopeful but is too long for me to summarize here.

Comment: Hum... my gac is nearly 3GB weight... i think my idea was not a very good idea